# How to get Scala Compiler Plugin to work in Scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, plugins, compiler-construction, scala-ide

*Note: This is an exact repost of the same question on the Scala-IDE mailing list, where I got zero reply and gave up waiting after 5 days.*

I'm writing a Scala Compiler Plugin. It's currently called
scalawrapper (but I might find a better name later). I have the
Typesafe Stack installed, and I put my plugin in it under:

```
C:\Program Files\typesafe-stack\misc\scala-devel\plugins
```

Now I can call scalac like this:

```
scalac -classpath ... -Xplugin-require:scalawrapper test\...
```

and it finds and uses my plugin automatically.

Unfortunately, I just can't get the Scala-IDE to use it. I always get
`Missing required plugin: scalawrapper`. In the "Project Properties
\Scala Compiler (Use Project Settings)\Advanced" tab, I have entered
scalawrapper in the Xplugin-require field, and that works, since I get
the error. But nothing I can type in Xpluginsdir seem to have any
effect.

I have tried the absolute path given above, have tried with forward
and backward slashes, have tried a temporary directory without spaces
in it, have tried relative to project directory, have tried relative
to workspace. It just will not use anything. I should also note that
is is not specific to my own plugin, as I tried to use the ScalaCL
plugin before in a previous version of the Scala-IDE, and failed for
the exact same reason.

I have just updated today (15.10.2011) and so should have the latest
version (it seems I can finally explicitly set the indentation to 4,
but maybe I just overlooked the setting in the past).

Can someone tell me what it actually expects, and what is uses as
default when I don't put anything in Xpluginsdir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Scala IDE uses the presentation compiler, not the compiler that you've installed. To use a plugin, with Scala IDE, you need to specify it in the preferences in Eclipse.

Try `Windows->Preferences->Scala->Compiler`. See the Advanced tab. The paths are relative to the workspace.

EDIT: When I say relative to the workspace, I mean the actual workspace directory under which the .metadata is stored (`$workspace_loc`). I have a project where project files including the source code is stored in one directory and the workspace is elsewhere, i.e the `$project_loc` (c:\code\project\source) is different from the `$workspace_loc` (c:\code\project\workspace). The directory that you specify in the compiler parameters is relative to the workspace (`$workspace_loc`).

To find out if you have a similar setup, go to the project and select `Properties->Resource->Linked Resources`.

I created a directory under `$workspace_loc` called plugin and placed the jar file in there. Under `Windows->Preferences->Scala->Compiler` Advanced tab I have

```
Xplugin = C:\code\project\workspace\plugin\xxx-0.0.1.jar
Xplugin-require = xxx
```

Please note that you can specify the plugin in the project properties as well, but it still uses `$workspace_loc`. The above configuration works for me.

Comment: You have not read my question. I know where the setting is: "In the "Project Properties \Scala Compiler (Use Project Settings)\Advanced" tab," The only problem is, that  IT DOESN'T WORK.

Comment: Sorry, I did read your question, but I wasn't explicit enough about what I meant. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. If I do it exactly like you said, it seems to work. I think the reason I thought it did not work before was that Eclipse throws away all output (both System.out and log(...)), so it looks like it did nothing. The same options that produce the output with scalac do nothing in Eclipse. I had to throw an exception to prove that it works, but that's a different problem to be solved in a different question. Have you ever found out how to use Xpluginsdir so that you don't have to specify the jar explicitly?