# How to use Scala macro paradise in Eclipse via Ivy

Tags: eclipse, scala, macros, ivy

I need some help, please.  I'm trying to create macro annotations and am having trouble enabling macro paradise in my Eclipse project (using Scala 2.11 in ScalaIDE).  I added an Ivy dependency for macro paradise:

```
 <dependency org="org.scalamacros" name="paradise_2.11.5" rev="2.1.0-M5" />
```

...and when I resolve it downloads the JAR OK, but I get a compiler error when I try to use a macro annotation saying I need to enable macro paradise.

Does anyone know how to do this in an Ivy-based project (without Maven or SBT)?  I tried configuring a macro paradise compiler via these instructions but it doesn't work (Eclipse can't seem to find it):

[How to get Scala Compiler Plugin to work in Scala IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848521/how-to-get-scala-compiler-plugin-to-work-in-scala-ide)

Here's what I specified in the Eclipse Scala -> Compiler -> Advanced properties:

```
Xplugin: C:\Users\Tom.eclipse\workspace\macro_test\paradise_2.11.5-2.1.0-M5.jar 
Xplugin-require: paradise_2.11.5
```

However it gives the following error: "Missing required plugin: paradise_2.11.5"

The workspace root folder is C:\Users\Tom.eclipse\workspace\macro_test. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

The name of the Macro paradise plugin is "macroparadise" ([source](https://github.com/scalamacros/paradise/blob/2.11.7/plugin/src/main/scala/org/scalamacros/paradise/Plugin.scala)). So Xplugin-require should be "macroparadise"